# limit inf /sup if $x_n\leq y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

I have just 2 problems :

1)
Find the $\limsup x_n$ and $\liminf x_n$  where $x_n= e^{-n}$.

2)
Let $x_n\leq y_n$  for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$   .
Show that $\liminf x_n\leq\liminf y_n$ and $\limsup x_n\leq\limsup y_n$

thanks..

Comment: What did you try? Do you know the definition of limsup and liminf? What happens if the sequence converges?

Comment: If I understand the second part correctly (you probably mean $X_n$ and $Y_n$ there), then this question have been asked before on this site: [Prove: $a_n \leq b_n \implies \limsup a_n \leq \limsup b_n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213719/prove-a-n-leq-b-n-implies-limsup-a-n-leq-limsup-b-n). In the first part you have a convergent sequence: [Sequence converges iff $\limsup = \liminf$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122755/sequence-converges-iff-limsup-liminf).

Comment: If you read the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) or tag-excerpt (which is shown as a popup when you are adding a tag), then you will see that the tag [tag:limit-theorems] is not a good tag for this question.

Comment: i have seen this answer but i need more explain so can any one help me to solve thanks

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that we work with the following definitions:
$$
\limsup x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{x_k; k\ge n\}\\
\liminf x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf\{x_k; k\ge n\}
$$
(There are several equivalent definitions of [limit superior and limit inferior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior); different authors prefer different definitions.)
We know that the above limits exists (but may be infinite) for any real sequence $(x_n)$.

---

The sequence $x_n=e^{-n}$ converges to $0$. If a sequence has a limit, then both $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of this sequence are equal to this limit.

If a sequence $x_n$ converges to limit $L$ then there is an $n_0$ such that $|x_n-L|<\varepsilon$ for $n\ge n_0$, which is the same as saying that
$$L-\varepsilon < x_n < L+\varepsilon \qquad \text{for }n\ge n_0.$$
This implies that for $n\ge n_0$ we have $\sup\{x_k; k\ge n\}\le L+\varepsilon$ and $\inf\{x_k; k\ge n\}\ge L-\varepsilon$; and thus
$$\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}L-\ve\le \liminf x_n \le \limsup x_n \le L+\ve.$$
These inequalities are true for any $\ve>0$, therefore we get $L=\liminf x_n=\limsup x_n$.

---

Now if we assume that $x_n\le y_n$ for each $n$, then we also have 
$$\sup\{x_k; k\ge n\} \le \sup\{y_k; k\ge n\}$$
for each $n$. Taking limit $n\to\infty$ we get
$$\limsup x_n \le \limsup y_n.$$

Comment: @leenaadam I've tried to give some explanation for the questions you are asking, but I don't think I have said here anything which has not been already said in the questions I linked to in [my comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350896/question-about-limit-inf-and-limit-sup/350918#comment754220_350896) above.
If there is still some part which you do not understand, please, let me know at which place exactly you have a problem.

Comment: The link in the preceding comment should have been [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350896/limit-inf-sup-if-x-n-leq-y-n-n/350918#comment754220_350896).