# (analysis) sequence a(n) is bounbed and sequence b(n) converges. Show that a(n)≤b(n) (∀ n ∈ ℕ) ⇒lim supa(n)≤lim b(n)

Tags: analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

sequence a(n) is bounbed and sequence b(n) converges. Show that
a(n)≤b(n) (∀ n ∈ ℕ) ⇒lim sup a(n)≤lim b(n)

Since a(n) is bounded, a(n) has a convergent subsequence. let a1'(n) be a subsequence of a(n). Then, a1'(n)≤b(n) (∀ n ∈ ℕ), a2'(n)≤b(n) (∀ n ∈ ℕ),...
ak'(n)≤b(n) (∀k∈ ℕ) thus, lim ak'(n)≤lim b(n) ⇒lim sup a(n)≤lim b(n)
Is this a valid proof?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: How do you define $\limsup$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213719/prove-a-n-leq-b-n-implies-limsup-a-n-leq-limsup-b-n and other quesions linked there.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is a valid proof.

First of all, how do you define $a_2^\prime(n)$?

Second, it is not because a subsequence of a sequence is always less that another sequence that $\limsup$ is also less.

A valid proof would be:

- As for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $b_n \le a_n$, you have $\limsup b_n \le \limsup a_n$. *Do you know this result? Can you prove it?*
- As $(a_n)$ is convergent, $\limsup a_n = \lim a_n$.
- Therefore $\limsup b_n \le \lim a_n$.